# Highchart multiseries issue for passing string using spring and jsp

Tags: highcharts

My problem is I have one string which has all the data in json right format but when I am giving this string in Highchart series oprtion it is not coming properly.

below is the scrip which is written in jsp:

```
<script>
    var blocksdata = '["(0-6)", "(6-12)" , "(12-24)", "(24-48)", "(48-72)", ">72"]';
var i;
function chartData (reportDataString) {
$('#TATChart').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
        text: 'TAT Data'
        },
        xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
        categories: JSON.parse(blocksdata),
                labels: {
                    rotation: -90,
                    style: {
                        fontSize: '13px',
                        fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
            text: 'Number of candidates verified'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },
    series: reportDataString
    });

};

    var processed_json1 = new Array();


     var url ='${pageContext.servletContext.contextPath}';
        $.ajax({ url: url+'/bgvservice/getChart',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
                var names = [];
                var values = [];
                for(i=0;i<data.finalData.length;i++){

                    names.push(data.finalData[i].key);
                    values.push(data.finalData[i].value);

                }

        var reportdata;
        var reportDataString;
        for(var i=0;i<names.length;i++) {

            reportdata = "{name: \""+names[i]+"\",data: "+values[i]+",dataLabels: {enabled: true,rotation: 0,color: '#FFFFFF',align: 'center',x: 4,y: 10,style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',textShadow: '0 0 3px black'}}}";        

            if(reportDataString!=undefined){
                reportDataString = reportDataString+','+reportdata;
                        }
            else
                reportDataString = reportdata;
                }

        alert('outside'+reportDataString);
                chartData(reportDataString);
    }
        });

        </script>
```

But chart is not displaying on page.
I not able to find the issue.

Comment: Because you should use JSON, not string. You can convert that by JSON.parse() function.

Comment: I tried with JSON.parse(reportDataString), Its giving below error: "VM389:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token n"                          JSON is printing as "[{name: "Whitefield - Dell 7",data: [4,0,0,0,0,0],dataLabels: {enabled: true,rotation: 0,color: '#FFFFFF',align: 'center',x: 4,y: 10,style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',textShadow: '0 0 3px black'}}},{name: "Bangalore",data: [4,0,0,0,0,0],dataLabels: {enabled: true,rotation: 0,color: '#FFFFFF',align: 'center',x: 4,y: 10,style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',textShadow: '0 0 3px black'}}}]"